# how to pass environment variable to dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

how to pass kaps-service as a environment variable to my dockerfile

file.txt:-
Match $Match
name  prod

dockerfile:-
FROM image
ENV Match=kaps-service
COPY file.txt /etc/

the requirement is I want to replace the $Match value in file.txt from dockerfile or can I pass this value while starting the docker container ? is there a way to do it ?

Comment: `file.txt` is a regular text file. No substitution will be done without any execution.

Comment: `ENV`s come from `docker run` (run step), so it's impossible to use it in Dockerfile (build step). You can use `ARG` instead or, as you said, during run step using an `entrypoint` to handle `ENV`s.

Answer (score 1):

From Dockerfile you can use something like:

```
FROM image

ARG Match="kaps-service"

COPY file.txt /etc/

RUN sed -i 's/$Match/'$Match'/g' /etc/file.txt
```

The last line will replace all occurrences of $Match with "kaps-service". This will happen during build step, and you can modify Match argument with the `--build-arg` flag

In case you want the replacement to be in run step (docker run) you can take the RUN command and put it in some script that will execute this command before your application. It can be something like:

```
FROM image

WORKDIR /app

ENV Match="kaps-service"

COPY file.txt /etc/
COPY run .

CMD "./run"
```

where `run` is:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i 's/$Match/'$Match'/g' /etc/file.txt
# run you app
```

The change will happen when you starts a container with `docker run` and you can modify Match variable add `-e Match=something` to the command.